# Sin respuesta xamarin.android obtener geolocalización (xamarin.essentials)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2017, xamarin, xamarin.android

Lo que sucede es que estoy usando el API proporcionado por Microsoft para usar Xamarin Essential en un proyecto hecho en xamarin.android, dónde estoy necesito usar los métodos para obtener la geolocalización, dónde ya he instalado el paquete (xamarin.essentials) por el administrador de paquetes nuget, cabe aclarar que el paquete lo he instalado en un proyecto independiente dónde sera usado como servicio en segundo plano.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android

Adjunto sección de código que utilizo. Ya he propocionado permisos de localización en la aplicación pero la aplicación no responde cuando llega a realizar la petición al método proporcionado por Microsoft (GetLocationAsync).

```
public Xamarin.Essentials.Location GetCurrentLocation()
    {
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;
        var currentLocation = new Location();
        try
        {
            var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Default,TimeSpan.MinValue);
            var locationResult = Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request).Result;

            if (locationResult != null)
            {
                currentLocation = locationResult;
            }
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ("{0}, : {1}", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace).ToString();
            Log.Error(TAG_LOG_LOCATION, "Error encontrado {0}", errorMessage);
        }
        catch (FeatureNotEnabledException ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ("{0}, : {1}", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace).ToString();
            Log.Error(TAG_LOG_LOCATION, "Error encontrado {0}", errorMessage);
        }
        catch (PermissionException ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ("{0}, : {1}", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace).ToString();
            Log.Error(TAG_LOG_LOCATION, "Error encontrado {0}", errorMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ("{0}, : {1}", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace).ToString();
            Log.Error(TAG_LOG_LOCATION, "Error encontrado {0}", errorMessage);
        }
        return currentLocation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola inicializaste el paquete en el MainActivity? `Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, Bundle);`
segundo te faltaria hacer que tenga el await el metodo y colocar Asycn en tu metodo, muchas veces o la mayoria esto evita que tu vista parezca que no responde cuando un proceso demora mucho tiempo en dar un resultado.
Yo uso esa libreria y lo uso sin el result al principio.
te deje el codigo de como  lo hago yo.

Saludos, marca la respuesta si te sirvio.

```
public async Xamarin.Essentials.Location GetCurrentLocation()
    {
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;
        var currentLocation = new Location();
        try
        {
            var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Default,TimeSpan.MinValue);
            var locationResult = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);

            if (locationResult != null)
            {
                currentLocation = locationResult;
            }
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ("{0}, : {1}", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace).ToString();
            Log.Error(TAG_LOG_LOCATION, "Error encontrado {0}", errorMessage);
        }
        catch (FeatureNotEnabledException ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ("{0}, : {1}", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace).ToString();
            Log.Error(TAG_LOG_LOCATION, "Error encontrado {0}", errorMessage);
        }
        catch (PermissionException ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ("{0}, : {1}", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace).ToString();
            Log.Error(TAG_LOG_LOCATION, "Error encontrado {0}", errorMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ("{0}, : {1}", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace).ToString();
            Log.Error(TAG_LOG_LOCATION, "Error encontrado {0}", errorMessage);
        }
        return currentLocation;
    }
```

Comment: Hola, tiene agregados await y async en los metodos, ya que su problema es que la vista se queda sin responder, y le pregunte si tenia inicializada la libreria en el MainActivity lo cual es necesario para Xamarin.Essentials. Leiste muy rapido.

Comment: Async ya lo tiene

Answer (score 0):

He logrado dar respuesta al fallo que estaba presentando, dónde el método lo volví asincrono, dónde retire el .Result cuando hago solicitud de localización, comparto fragmento de código.

Nota: El servicio de localización de xamarin essential lo uso en un servicio en segundo plano de android.

```
public async Task<Location> GetCurrentLocationAsync()
    {
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;
        Location locationResult = null;
        try
        {
            var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Best);
            locationResult = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);              
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ("{0}, : {1}", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace).ToString();
            Log.Error(TAG_LOG_LOCATION, "Error encontrado {0}", errorMessage);
        }
        catch (FeatureNotEnabledException ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ("{0}, : {1}", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace).ToString();
            Log.Error(TAG_LOG_LOCATION, "Error encontrado {0}", errorMessage);
        }
        catch (PermissionException ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ("{0}, : {1}", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace).ToString();
            Log.Error(TAG_LOG_LOCATION, "Error encontrado {0}", errorMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ("{0}, : {1}", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace).ToString();
            Log.Error(TAG_LOG_LOCATION, "Error encontrado {0}", errorMessage);
        }
        return locationResult;
    }
```

Saludos!!!

Comment: por lo que veo tu respuesta es idéntica a la que te di en primero momento.